# Mule HTTPS access

Tags: https, mule, mule-studio

To access my test I use `http://hostDesired.com/service?WSDL`: it's a regular service proxy running direct into Mule.

How can I change it to be able to access using `https://hostDesired.com/service?WSDL`? What I tried and did not work was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ssl="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
    xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
    xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.4/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.4/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.4/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.4/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl/current/mule-ssl.xsd" version="EE-3.4.0">

    <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
            name="memory-dao" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>

    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="userService">
                    <ss:user name="asd" password="asd" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

    <https:connector name="httpsConnector">
    <https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks"
        keyPassword="${jks.password}" storePassword="${jks.password}" />
    </https:connector>

    <pattern:web-service-proxy name="ProxyService"
          inboundAddress="https://desiredHost/services/Services/Service"
          outboundAddress="http://remoteHost/services/Service.svc"
          wsdlLocation="http://remoteHost/services/Service.svc?singleWSDL"/>

</mule>
```

It didn't work... how or what can i do to change it into Mule?

The basic idea is to add encryption from client to the proxy server.

Comment: Mule version? What error do you get? Stacktrace? Also please show how you've configured the `HTTPS` connector.

Comment: Hi David, version is 3.4 and didnt added anything, didnt found anything related so still using the same pattern as before only using https instead of http... by your message i should be using some sort of connector, but since i just new to Mule Studio + Mule i have no clue...

Comment: The configuration shows `http://desiredHost/services/Services/Service`: shouldn't it be `https:...`?

Comment: I did try with https there but got no reply from server, let me try something else and i will give you a feed back asap.

Comment: Yes, please post the exception you're getting.

Comment: Ok, did another try `https://desiredHost/services/Services/Service?WSDL` and got no answer.... in chrome it says page cannot be loaded,,,

Comment: I thought you wanted HTTPS...

Comment: it is HTTPS, ive posted the wrong type and changed again, sorry....

Comment: So what it is actual configuration you are running? Please update your question, it's hard to follow where you're at. Also do you get any stacktrace on Mule? If yes, please post in the question. Finally: do you use a self-signed certificate or a real one?

Comment: ok i did change the question according to the last version im configuring at Mule Studio, i never had to use things that way and by the tips you are giving i will need to create a self signed c ertificate and store it somewhere and point it into Mule, i have no clue on how to do it, but i will search...

Comment: The process for creating a self-signed certificate is documented at the beginning of the HTTPS reference page linked in my answer: did you read it?

Comment: I will read it again more carefully and see what im missing...

Comment: ok i did follow all the steps and created the keystore.jks file and placed at muleHome/conf location pointed into path with ${mule.home}/conf/keystore.jks and for sure im using https:// in front of that host name, and after all those tryes the server still not answering... What else can i do?

Comment: Oh you installed the keystore in Mule standalone, not in your apps classpath? I guess that works too as `$MULE_HOME/conf` is on the classpath. You should be getting stacktraces in the server logs, otherwise there's no reason for this not to work.

Comment: Nothing on my log files, just that the project is running... want me to send the code by email or something? so far what i did was creare locally the keystore.jks and send it to the server where im doing my tests, storing that file at the mule stand alone config dir and pointing it at the path, but nothing appears to work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an HTTPS inbound endpoint, you need to configure the HTTPS connector so Mule knows what certificate(s) to use when handling the requests.

Refer to the HTTPS connector's configuration page: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTPS+Transport+Reference

Since it's quite confusing on the doc, let me add that all you need is a correctly configured `https:tls-key-store` element in `https:connector`, similar to:

```
<https:connector name="httpsConnector">
    <https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks"
        keyPassword="${jks.password}" storePassword="${jks.password}" />
</https:connector>
```

This sample assumes that your keystore file is named `keystore.jks` and is available on the classpath. Also it assumes that you have declared the `jks.password` property and that you use the same password for both the keystore and the key. **Adapt it to your own situation**.

Comment: Ok just added the full test code, lets see if now its more clear. Was trying to search for more answers but google went down :/